# "Printing" 3D structures using an atom laser?

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate, coherence

An [atom laser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_laser) is a coherent beam of atoms, similar to a laser. This is formed through use of Bose-Einstein condensate.

Could such a beam be focused and used to deposit atoms on a surface to build up an atomically-precise nanoscale object?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done with a normal (optical) laser. It actually won the Nobel prize this year, it's called *optical tweezers*.

Some cool structures people built 'atom by atom' are Eiffel towers, Moebius strips etc ([paper](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-018-0450-2)):

[image]

With an atom laser, the atoms would be moving so you'd need to somehow stop them before they can be "deposited" to be part of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. The lenses and other optical components can be provided by an optical effect called the dipole force (the same effect used in optical tweezers).

One would have all the usual technical problems regarding stability of the positioning of these elements, and the flux of atoms would be small, so one could only build small things to begin with.

Another way to aim for atomic-level precision is to start with individual atomic ions in a trap, and transport them using changing electric potentials.